# How to understand ACPI _OSC method defined in DSDT table

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, acpi

I am new to ACPI.
And I am trying to understand _OSC method defined in following DSDT table within Linux host.

```asl
        Name (SUPP, 0x00)
        Name (CTRL, 0x00)
        Method (_OSC, 4, NotSerialized)
        {
            CreateDWordField (Arg3, 0x00, CDW1)
            CreateDWordField (Arg3, 0x04, CDW2)
            CreateDWordField (Arg3, 0x08, CDW3)
            If (LEqual (Arg0, Buffer (0x10)
                    {
                        /* 0000 */    0x5B, 0x4D, 0xDB, 0x33, 0xF7, 0x1F, 0x1C, 0x40, 
                        /* 0008 */    0x96, 0x57, 0x74, 0x41, 0xC0, 0x3D, 0xD7, 0x66
                    }))
            {
                Store (CDW2, SUPP)
                Store (CDW3, CTRL)
                And (CTRL, 0x0C, CTRL)
                If (LNotEqual (Arg1, 0x01))
                {
                    Or (CDW1, 0x0A, CDW1)
                }

                If (LNotEqual (CDW3, CTRL))
                {
                    Or (CDW1, 0x10, CDW1)
                }

                Store (CTRL, CDW3)
            }
            Else
            {
                Or (CDW1, 0x06, CDW1)
            }

            Return (Arg3)
        }
```

What does this method do, such as where are the SUPP/CTRL ?

Comment: What do you mean by "where are SUPP/CTRL"? You can see their definition at the top of your snippet.

Comment: I suggest you to read ACPI specification. It has all terms explained.